# Why the name variable does not exist in the current context?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a C# ASP.net core application deployed on Ubuntu. This application has some references written in VB.Net.

When deploying the app to Ubuntu I'm remote-debugging the app with Visual Studio.

When debugging, everywhere in my code I'm not able to see the values of the variables. I checked almost all the parameters I know. The debugger stops properly on the break points, but the watch doesn't work. I'm getting : **the name "MyVariable" does not exist in the current context.**

Here is what I checkd :

**1 - The app is published in debug mode :**

[image]

[image]

**2 - In the compiler, the optimisation is disabled :**

[image]

**3 - The variables I'm trying to watch are used in the code. Hence not removed by the compiler optimisation or whatever**

[image]

**4 - Screenshot of the debugger stopping at the break point**

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve that please ?

Thanks

Comment: The pdb file contains the debugging info.  It need to be in same folder where executable is located.

Comment: @jdweng it's and it's also uploaded to the server.

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/specify-symbol-dot-pdb-and-source-files-in-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2019

Comment: @jdweng I'm sorry I don't understand. The pdb files are properly generated in the right folder and published to the server as I said

Comment: Including the VB dll?  The c# app pdb does not inlude the VB debug info.

Comment: No eveything is included. Even vb.net libraries pdb files are included.

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of the debugger stopped on a breakpoint and the watch window having problems?

Comment: @CaiusJard I added a screenshot of the debugger stopping on a breakpoint as well as the watch window.

Comment: Does the locals window show that anything is in scope?